# Hibernate PostgreSQL OneToOne Relationship Trigger Child Query First

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm building app to learn Hibernate on PostgreSQL. And I'm currently trying to add variable to database that has OneToOne relationship.

First, I create two tables in my database with schema below. On `person_detail` table it has primary key that's also foreign key to `person` table.

[image: Database Schema]

Then I created two classes, `Person` and `PersonDetail`. `PersonDetail` is child of `Person` that has OneToOne relationship. And I use code below to add `person` with `personDetail` as attribute.

```
Person person = new Person(
        "Rick",
        1.7,
        dateFromString("1969-4-2"),
        new Date()
);
PersonDetail personDetail =
        new PersonDetail("myemail@email.com", "Marley");
person.setPersonDetail(personDetail);

session.beginTransaction();

session.save(person);
session.save(personDetail);

session.getTransaction().commit();

System.out.println(person.toString());
```

But the problem with code above is that Hibernate execute child query first instead of parent query.

> Hibernate: insert into person_detail (address, email) values (?, ?)

And since `person` still empty, we cannot insert any row to `person_detail` because it violates foreign key constraint.

Is there a way to solve this?
Thanks!

In case some one want to check how I annotate those two classes, I put the code below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
@Data
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="height")
    private double height;

    @Column(name="birth_date")
    private Date dateBirth;

    @Column(name="last_seen")
    private Date lastSeen;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private PersonDetail personDetail;

    public Person() {}

    public Person(String name, double height, Date dateBirth, Date lastSeen){
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
        this.dateBirth = dateBirth;
        this.lastSeen = lastSeen;
    }
}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="person_detail")
public class PersonDetail {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    public PersonDetail(){}

    public PersonDetail(String email, String address){
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have primary key in table `person_details` as foreign key to `person` table, you can use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
@Data
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "height")
    private String height;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private PersonDetail personDetail;

    public Person() {}

    public Person(String name, String height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
    }
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="person_detail")
public class PersonDetail {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Person person;


    public PersonDetail(){}

    public PersonDetail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

And if you save your entity, don't forget set Person to PersonDetails:

```
Person person = new Person("Rick", "1.7");
        
PersonDetail personDetail = new PersonDetail("myemail@email.com");
personDetail.setPerson(person);

person.setPersonDetail(personDetail);
        
repository.save(person);
```

Comment: Hi, I try this yet it introduces another problem. But thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: hi, which problem?

Comment: It turns out I didn't add some annotation. and it works! thank you so much! So, if I make conclusion from your code, to make OneToOne relatisionship we need to add both `person` and `person_detail` attribute in both classes, right?

Comment: No, a one to one can be unidirectional. Check the hibernate ORM documentation for several examples on how to map associations: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one